# Groupwise sorting in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, pandas-groupby

I want to sort an array within the group boundaries defined in another array. The groups are not presorted in any way and need to remain unchanged after the sorting. In `numpy` terms it would look like this:

```
import numpy as np

def groupwise_sort(group_idx, a, reverse=False):
    sortidx = np.lexsort((-a if reverse else a, group_idx))
    # Reverse sorting back to into grouped order, but preserving groupwise sorting
    revidx = np.argsort(np.argsort(group_idx, kind='mergesort'), kind='mergesort')
    return a[sortidx][revidx]

group_idx =   np.array([3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1])
a =           np.array([3, 2, 1, 7, 4, 5, 5, 9, 1])
groupwise_sort(group_idx, a)
# >>>            array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 7, 5, 9])
groupwise_sort(group_idx, a, reverse=True)
# >>>            array([3, 7, 1, 5, 4, 9, 2, 5, 1])
```

How can I do the same with `pandas`? I saw `df.groupby()` and `df.sort_values()`, though I couldn't find a straight forward way to achieve the same sorting. And a fast one, if possible.

Comment: I think if solution working nice in numpy, not necessary `pandas` solution, mainly if need `fast` one. Or what is reason for use `pandas`?

Comment: I'm developing `numpy_groupies`, a bunch of aggregating functions on top of `numpy` and `numba` https://github.com/ml31415/numpy-groupies . For comparing and benchmarking I'm frequently using `pandas`.

Comment: About being fast with it, well it's not super crucial for myself, `pandas` is usually painfully slow anyways, so that I don't use it. I just want to avoid taking blame for doing unfair benchmarks.

Answer (score 5):

Let us first set the stage:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

group_idx =   np.array([3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1])
a =           np.array([3, 2, 1, 7, 4, 5, 5, 9, 1])

df = pd.DataFrame({'group': group_idx, 'values': a})
df
#   group  values
#0      3       3
#1      2       2
#2      3       1
#3      2       7
#4      2       4
#5      1       5
#6      2       5
#7      1       9
#8      1       1
```

#### To get a dataframe sorted by group and values (within groups):

```
df.sort_values(["group", "values"])

#   group  values
#8      1       1
#5      1       5
#7      1       9
#1      2       2
#4      2       4
#6      2       5
#3      2       7
#2      3       1
#0      3       3
```

To sort the values in descending order, use `ascending = False`. To apply different orders to different columns, you can supply a list:

```
df.sort_values(["group", "values"], ascending = [True, False])

#   group  values
#7      1       9
#5      1       5
#8      1       1
#3      2       7
#6      2       5
#4      2       4
#1      2       2
#0      3       3
#2      3       1
```

Here, groups are sorted in ascending order, and the values within each group are sorted in descending order.

#### To only sort values for contiguous rows belonging to the same group, create a new group indicator:

(I keep this in here for reference since it might be helpful for others. I wrote this in an earlier version before the OP clarified his question in the comments.)

```
df['new_grp'] = (df.group.diff(1) != 0).astype('int').cumsum()
df
#   group  values  new_grp
#0      3       3        1
#1      2       2        2
#2      3       1        3
#3      2       7        4
#4      2       4        4
#5      1       5        5
#6      2       5        6
#7      1       9        7
#8      1       1        7
```

We can then easily sort with `new_grp` instead of `group`, leaving the original order of groups untouched.

#### Ordering within groups but keeping the group-specifing row-positions:

To sort the elements of each group but keep the group-specific positions in the dataframe, we need to keep track of the original row numbers. For instance, the following will do the trick:

```
# First, create an indicator for the original row-number:

df["ind"] = range(len(df))

# Now, sort the dataframe as before
df_sorted = df.sort_values(["group", "values"])

# sort the original row-numbers within each group
newindex = df.groupby("group").apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(["ind"]))["ind"].values

# assign the sorted row-numbers to the sorted dataframe
df_sorted["ind"] = newindex

# Sort based on the row-numbers:
sorted_asc = df_sorted.sort_values("ind")

# compare the resulting order of values with your desired output:
np.array(sorted_asc["values"])
# array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 7, 5, 9])
```

This is easier to test and profile when written up in a function, so let's do that:

```
def sort_my_frame(frame, groupcol = "group", valcol = "values", asc = True):

    frame["ind"] = range(len(frame))
    frame_sorted = frame.sort_values([groupcol, valcol], ascending = [True, asc])
    ind_sorted = frame.groupby(groupcol).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(["ind"]))["ind"].values
    frame_sorted["ind"] = ind_sorted
    frame_sorted = frame_sorted.sort_values(["ind"])

    return(frame_sorted.drop(columns = "ind"))

np.array(sort_my_frame(df, "group", "values", asc = True)["values"])
# array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 7, 5, 9])
np.array(sort_my_frame(df, "group", "values", asc = False)["values"])
# array([3, 7, 1, 5, 4, 9, 2, 5, 1])
```

Note that the latter results match your desired outcome.

I am sure this can be written up in a more succinct way. For instance, if the index of your `dataframe` is already ordered, you can use that one instead of the indicator `ind` I create (i.e., following @DJK's comment, we can use `sort_index` instead of `sort_values` and avoid assigning an additional column). In any case, the above highlights one possible solution and how to approach it. An alternative would be to use your `numpy` functions and wrap the output around a `pd.DataFrame`.

Comment: Ok, looks like I provided not the best example, as my group_idx was already sorted. The idea is, whatever the group_idx is, not assuming it is sorted in any way, it should remain untouched after the operation.

Comment: This does not produce the correct result: 
`groupwise_sort(group_idx, a); # >>> array([ 1,  2,  3,  3,  4,  1,  5,  5, 10])`.

Comment: I really just want to flip the values of a within their groups. If the group is consecutive or not should not matter.

Comment: Ugh, I really hope there is a more elegant way to do that in pandas. I actually can't use my numpy implementation, as i want to benchmark pandas against it. With that one I don't even need to start benchmarking.

Comment: To be honest, I dont quite see the point of this benchmark anyway. pandas is built on top of numpy, so I would be surprised to see any numpy solution slower than the pandas solution, as pandas involves additional functional overhead.

Comment: Pandas is widely used, implements many operations itself in cython and prides itself on being a high-performance solution. So benchmarking against it makes perfect sense, if you're writing similar software.

Comment: I agree with @coffeinjunky. The `.values` attributes of the dataframe and series objects return numpy ndarrays when you need access to the lower level objects. I also question the utility of this exercise. Can you share a specific use case for this functionality? I can't think of one off the top of my head.

Comment: I was going to post this but the approach is too similar to yours `df.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(['values'])).sort_index(level=1).reset_index(drop=True)`, you can avoid creating a seperate column as the index and remove one sort statement and the `.values`

Comment: @DJK yeah, I was initially thinking along similar lines. The reason why I create a new row indicator is that the dataframe might have an pre-existing but (for whatever reason) unsorted index (sorting on the index afterwards would thus mess with the output Michael wants). In any case, the problem remains that at some point we need to "break" the mapping between the index and the values (within group).

Answer (score 1):

Pandas is built on top of numpy. Assuming a dataframe like so:

```
df
Out[21]: 
   group  values
0      3       3
1      2       2
2      3       1
3      2       7
4      2       4
5      1       5
6      2       5
7      1       9
8      1       1
```

Call your function.

```
groupwise_sort(df.group.values, df['values'].values)
Out[22]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 7, 5, 9])

groupwise_sort(df.group.values, df['values'].values, reverse=True)
Out[23]: array([3, 7, 1, 5, 4, 9, 2, 5, 1])
```

Comment: Note that I _don't_ want to call my function and only provided that function for reference. I'm looking for a solution using exclusively pandas inbuilt functions.

Comment: Exactly! You can also wrap the outcome of that function into a `pd.DataFrame` or reassign the outcome to the initial column if you want to keep it as a dataframe.